Replace function call with resulting string literal during transpilation
Can I use a transpiler like Babel to replace a call to a function which returns a string with the return value as a string literal if the function parameters are known in advance?
The function would be something like:
function getColor(luminance) {
    return `hsl(100deg, 100%, ${luminance}%)`;
}

I would like all the various function calls to be replaced with a string literal in the transpiled code:
var someCssValueToBeUsed = getColor(50);

var someCssValueToBeUsed = "hsl(100deg, 100%, 50%)";


If this is meant as a performance optimization the chance of that affecting anything is extremely minimal.

@loganfsmyth that's probably true, bit I'm still curious if a transpiler could do something like that
